# C# Serialize expression

Tags: c#, .net, database, linq, serialization

I would like to serialize expression. (Create IQuery clientside -> Send it to server -> Execute -> Return result to Client)

But honestly expressions are not serializeable. With the gnupacket Serialize.Linq (https://github.com/esskar/Serialize.Linq) I still have a problem. Following exception will be thrown:

> Error converting type: Der Typ 'Prog.DB.Query`1[[Prog.Database.User,
>   Prog.Database, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]]' mit dem Datenvertragsnamen
>   'ArrayOfUser:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Prog.Database'
>   wird nicht erwartet. Verwenden Sie ggf. einen DataContractResolver,
>   oder fügen Sie alle unbekannten Typen statisch der Liste der bekannten
>   Typen hinzu, beispielsweise mithilfe des KnownTypeAttribute-Attributs
>   oder indem Sie sie zur Liste der bekannten Typen hinzufügen, die an
>   DataContractSerializer übergeben wird.

I added all known types with

`JsonSerializer js = new JsonSerializer();
js.AddKnownTypes(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Prog.Database.User)).GetTypes().Where(t => !ignoreList.Contains(t)).ToList());`

Adding `js.AddKnownType(typeof(List<Prog.Database.User>));` throws another exception

> Error converting type: Der Typ
>   "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[LISA.Database.User]" kann der Liste
>   bekannter Typen nicht hinzugefügt werden, da bereits ein anderer Typ
>   "LISA.Database.User[]" mit demselben Datenvertragsnamen
>   "schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/LISA.Database:ArrayOfUser"
>   vorhanden ist. Wenn verschiedene Auflistungen eines bestimmten Typs
>   vorhanden sind, z. B. List und Test[], können nicht beide als
>   bekannte Typen hinzugefügt werden. Fügen Sie ggf. nur einen dieser
>   Typen der Liste der bekannten Typen hinzu.

Database is serializable (Serialization Mode: Unidirectional) and [DataMember] + [DataContract] attributes are set as well. Serialization without expression (just database objects) works fine.

Comment: Why give such a wide interface? You can use expression trees to do literally anything safe that .NET allows you to do - are you sure you want to allow your clients to send `format c:` to your server? It's not all that hard to make your own expression trees that are far more limited.

Comment: Because Linq is very convenient to use and I dont want to write pure SQL or create Commands for every possible select.

Comment: @ThomasChristof Sure! Could you send me the details of your server? I could run almost any code on your server if you open up your server to Expressions.

Comment: You know, you can use LINQ without using .NET's expression trees. There's no magic involved - it's just functions taking arguments, and returning a value. It's not even particularly hard - I've already made a few providers both on top of .NET's Expressions and otherwise - all nicely strongly-typed and everything.

Comment: Yup, but I cant serialize that neither. Maybe some references could help me. Could you please provide me any further information about your implementations?

Comment: @Aron The server has no connection to the GAN. Just running in the intranet. Plus the database user has limited privilegs.

Comment: Solved the problem by implementing my own expression serializer.